# rssReader Saving a MWFeed to Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, save, feed

I have url.rss and I parse it with MWFeed. I have Feeditem and feedinfo . I need save this information to coreData. How can i do this?

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, MWFeedParserDelegate {

```
var feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()




let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext



func request() {
    let URL = NSURL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss")
    let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: URL);
    feedParser.delegate = self
    feedParser.parse()
}


// Feed Pars delegate

func feedParserDidStart(parser: MWFeedParser!) {
    feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()
}

func feedParserDidFinish(parser: MWFeedParser!) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func feedParser(parser: MWFeedParser!, didParseFeedInfo info: MWFeedInfo!) {
    print(info)
    self.title = info.title
}

func feedParser(parser: MWFeedParser!, didParseFeedItem item: MWFeedItem!) {
    print(item)

   self.feedItems.append(item)
}

func saveToCoreData() {


    let entityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("FeedTitle", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let title = FeedTitle(entity: entityDescripition!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    title.title = ???????
    do{
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    }catch{
        print(error)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a method that creates a new managed object and saves changes. What part don't you understand? You have a bunch of `?` on one line where you're assigning the title-- that would appear to be where you want to assign the value of the title.

Comment: I am not understand how i can save all of this to coredata. Please explain on fingers ) this metod dont work. How add feeditem and feedinfo to managedobjectContext? Or maybe another desigion?)

Comment: You already have code to add an object to the managed object context, and to save changes. I can't tell what your question is.